# PHP Switch Language not working if URL include @username

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to switch language.

en for English
id for Indonesia

lang.php

```
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX
if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}   
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
    $lang = 'en';
}

switch ($lang)
{
    case 'en':
    $lang_file = 'assets/lang/lang.en.php';
    break;

    case 'id':
    $lang_file = 'assets/lang/lang.id.php';
    break;
    
    default:
    $lang_file = 'assets/lang/lang.en.php';
}
include_once $lang_file;
```

lang.id.php

```
$lang['LOGIN'] = 'Masuk';
```

lang.en.php

```
$lang['LOGIN'] = 'Login';
```

I have tried the code and it works with example URL : http://example.com/?lang=id or http://example.com/?lang=en

Now I implement URL like this:
http://example.com/john?lang=en

but it's not work.

here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

My question why when the URL :

http://example.com/?lang=en or http://example.com/?lang=id works

but not for this URL

http://example.com/john?lang=en

Comment: Change `[L]` to `[L,QSA]`.